# akka actor generic receive method

Tags: scala, akka

I have implemented a class that takes generic parameters for a function, the funtion signature looks like

```
def getPreparedStatement[T >: AnyVal](messagesForHBase: MessagesForHBase[T]):List[String]
```

I have to pass `MessagesForHBase` from the calling method to akka actor. Does receive function of akka takes generic parameter, I am getting receive method not implemented if I do

```
//For akka actor    
 def receive[T >: AnyVal] = {
    case messages:MessagesForHBase[T] => updateStatements(messages)
    case _ => printf("Error unknow paramenter")
 }
```

Is there any way I can have function take generic parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; the `receive` method must have type `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`. What you can do is to implement your own function, and use the proper `receive` to delegate to it.

Comment: Thanks for quick one!!

Comment: @alf Could you pls paste an example? How would you do that without casting?

Comment: @lisak, you pattern match, in exactly the same way as OP does. It's just that you cannot change the type signature—it is defined by the Akka itself.